# Unable to sendkeys using webdriverjs specifically F11 to maximise the browser

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

With the below code block it opens a chrome browser fine it just won't full screen the browser using F11. i used to use C# and selenium and that worked fine using this method on chrome and different browsers. It finds the element 'body' but then does not send the key press. Am I doing something wrong here that i should be requiring some other library?

the documentation for webdriverjs is pathetic and there is very few examples, I am seriously considering dumping it for something else possibly python.

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
    withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).
    build();
driver.get('https://www.google.co.uk/');

driver.wait(function () {
    return driver.getTitle().then(function (title) {
        return title === 'Google';
    });
}, 1000);


driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath('/html/body')).sendKeys("F11");
```

why are we doing this. we are developing a website that will change depending on size 800x600 + with and without the toolbar depending on how the screen is used different items will be displayed. i can maximise the window using,

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

This however still leaves the toolbar present and doesn't act as if the user has pressed the F11 key.

Comment: There is already the ability to maximise the window: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/webdriver/webdriver.js#L1254

Comment: The difference is that F11 hides the web address bar, and any other tool bars.

Comment: @Richard and that's practical, how?

Comment: in the website we are creating it has to be full screen for operational purposes therefore the address bar is not needed the maximize is not what i need (however i can get that to work :D)

Comment: Hello! So did you fix that problem? I also want to open the browser in fullscreen not just maximized. kind regards Margo

Comment: @Margo yes and no. I ended up switching to python where all my troubles vanished overnight and i managed to get a lot more tests done in a shorter time 
self.sendKeysWithClick(self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.main.list.ng-scope'), Keys.F11) using the ccs element to find the main body to press F11 on. using the names in css made testing a lot easier as i could just find it by this and then action against it. so no i didn't get it to work in javascript sorry

Answer (score 4):

it tooks some time to find it but you should have all the Keys in webdriver.Key

```
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath('/html/body')).sendKeys(webdriver.Key.F11);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Note that the method is now "Key" (singular) NOT "Keys" (plural)

Answer (score 2):

A co-worker has just discovered that it works well in C# with:

```
Driver.Instance.Manage().Window.FullScreen();
```

Comment: Hi there this question was for Javascript and not c# but this will come in handy so thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.F11).perform()
```

I use a similar command to toggle JS via Firefox's NoScript add-on

edit: I just tested, and it works!

Comment: Hi user2426679, this question was for Javascript and not python. and this still doesn't work with chromedriver.exe

Comment: What's the exact code you're trying? In your initial post you're sending F11 to an element (not an action chain).

Comment: A similar code works in C# with ChromeDriver.exe: `Actions act = new Actions(driver); act.SendKeys(Keys.F11); act.Build().Perform();`

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath('/html/body')).sendKeys(Keys.F11);
```

Comment: nope this does not work either... Keys is not defined (sendKeys.F11 is and this also does not work) thanks for the input though

Comment: Try "webdriver.Key" instead of "webdriver.Keys"

Answer (score 0):

You can maximise the window using:

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Comment: this again leaves the toolbar at the top something at that we don't want to do as we are creating an internal website that will need the full acreage of the screen, then dependant on size of screen we will be able to css items off the website.

Comment: Fullscreen display is a browser specific implementation, so unless selenium supports a specific behaviour per browser I doubt you will have access to this functionality. Also, I specifically don't think you want to be able to send the F11 to the DOM, otherwise lots of horrible things could happen.

Comment: Hi JamesK, this is true but with the 'selenium-webdriver' you are supposed to be implementing what a user would be doing ie a user pressing F11 and yes selenium does support it in other iterations (managed to get it working in c# using          driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body")).SendKeys(Keys.F11);) I am open to any other ideas to set this as it is needed for testing purposes. I was trying to keep all the language the same so that we don't have to change mind sets when working on the test code and the dev code.

Comment: I still wouldn't expect that to work, since you're sending keys to the DOM element. However I would expect the advanced user actions to perform it, i.e. driver.actions().sendKeys(webdriver.sendKeys.F11) which they don't seem to (note I'm using chrome - haven't tried on other browsers). I don't know why sorry. If you specifically just want to test in full screen mode and are using Chrome, you could try sending it a command line parameter to start in kiosk mode, I'm not sure if that would suit your need though.

Answer (score 0):

For me the one emulating correctly the F11 on startup is:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--start-fullscreen");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Or if the kiosk mode is preferred:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--kiosk");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```